# Error when inserting records into database in windows forms app

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

When debugging, an error happens on this line of code:

```
int StartKmReading = Convert.ToInt32(txtDTStartKmReading);
```

This is the errpr

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Data types and names of the database are correct as well.

Please help me with this. Thanks

```
private void btnAddDT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String InvoiceNo = txtDTInvoice.Text;
        String VehicleNo = txtDTVehicleNo.Text;
        String PackageType = txtDTPackageType.Text;
        DateTime StartTime = dtpStartTimeDT.Value;
        DateTime EndTime = dtpEndtimeDT.Value;
        int StartKmReading = Convert.ToInt32(txtDTStartKmReading);
        int EndKmReading = Convert.ToInt32(txtDTEndKmReading.Text);

        double BaseHire = Convert.ToDouble(txtBaseHireChargeDT.Text);
        double WaitingFee = Convert.ToDouble(txtWaitingFeeDT.Text);
        double ExtraKmCharge = Convert.ToDouble(txtExtraKmChargeDT.Text);
        double TotalAmount = Convert.ToDouble(txtDTTotalAmountCal.Text);

        conn.Open();

        String addQ = "insert into DayTourHires Values ('" + InvoiceNo + "', '" + VehicleNo + "', '" + PackageType + "', '" + StartTime+ "', '" + EndTime + "', '" + StartKmReading + "', '" + EndKmReading + "', '" + BaseHire + "', '" + WaitingFee + "', '" + ExtraKmCharge + "', '" + TotalAmount + "')";

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(addQ, conn);
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Record inserted");
    }   
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

The data should be successfully stored in the database without errors.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(txtDTStartKmReading);` - you need to get the `Text` property from `txtDTStartKmReading` like all your other textboxes.  This code is also open to SQL injection

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in this line code

```
int StartKmReading = Convert.ToInt32(txtDTStartKmReading);
```

It should be:

```
int StartKmReading = Convert.ToInt32(txtDTStartKmReading.Text);
```

But be careful. If the user enter a not valid value in the textboxes your code will throw an exception.
You should use `int.TryParse` method to make your code stronger